# Which data structure should I use to count words and the docs in which they appear?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, counter

I'm going through a list of documents, counting how many time each word appears globally, and storing in which documents. Therefore, I need a data structure which is more or less a dict with the key being the word and the value being a count and a list of document IDs.

Basically like that, I guess ? :

```
{
'word1': [num1, [id1, id2, id3]],
'word2': [num2, [id2, id4, id5]],
'word3': [num3, [id1, id4, id6, id]]
}
```

Is there such kind of thing ?

What I need is :

- a new row must be created if the word I'm pushing doesn't already exist,
- the `num` field must be easy to increment,
- the list of `id`s to be easy to update with a new document `id`

Should I use a dict ? Or something else ? I can see how I could do with a `list` with `['word', num, [id1, id2, id3]]` for each word, but I feel the code will be quite complicated for something that easy, so I'm wondering if there is some other data structure I don't know of which is better for my use ?

Comment: What is the primary use case? e.g. Do you want to know how many documents have a specific word? Or how many unique words in a given document? This will make a difference on what you should key and what you should value. So start by thinking about how your structure will be used. Will you need random access or sequential access?

Comment: I want to display the 30 most frequent words, so that I can have an idea of what are the things are the most frequently mentionned (the documents are actually tweets). Once they're found, I get rid of every other words. The IDs must be stored because I want the tweets in which a given word appear to be easy to find. I'm mostly interested in making sure it's reasonably quick (it's in a script that can be run multiple times per minute). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict as ddict
import re

s = "the task is to find the frequency of words in multiple docs"
ids = { 'the': [1,2,4], 'frequency' : [2,3] , 'of' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'words': [8] } 
d = ddict(int) 

# build the histogram of words: 
for w in re.findall('\w+',s):
   d[w] += 1

# new dictionary of frequency and ids:
new_ids = ddict(list)

for k in d:
    new_ids[k].append(d[k])
for k in ids:
    new_ids[k].append(ids[k])
```

Output:

```
>>> new_ids
ddict(list,
            {'docs': [1],
             'find': [1],
             'frequency': [1, [2, 3]],
             'in': [1],
             'is': [1],
             'multiple': [1],
             'of': [1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
             'task': [1],
             'the': [2, [1, 2, 4]],
             'to': [1], 
             'words': [1, [8]]})
```

In other words, one approach is to combine default dictionaries to take advantage of their features to easily create counts and append lists to values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to hashing with Chaining concept.
please go through the document [here](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/5_1_Hashing_with_Chaining.html)
worst case complexity is O(n).